# Casting a child class to a parent class seems to keep the object as the child class

Tags: c#, class, casting

I have two classes,Parent and Child.  Instances myParent and myChild

Child has a few more properties than the Parent. I need to remove these extra properties from a Child Instance by Casting it as a Parent Class.

I am using a ShallowCopy method to copy the state of the myChild instance into the myParent instance.

When I cast

```
myParent = new Parent();
myParent=((Parent)myChild).ShallowCopy();
```

and then

```
Debug.Print($"The myParent class is class'{myParent.GetType()}'");
```

I find the myParent class is actually a Child class!  I cant understand why.  I'd appreciate if someone could explain why.  Thanks!

Comment: Casting doesn't change the underlying object's type, it just changes how it is treated in the code.  I'm assuming you have it set up like `class Child : Parent` somewhere?  I'm also assuming that `ShallowCopy` is actually doing `Object.MemberwiseClone`, which will create an instance of the same type that is being cloned (myChild) with the same members.

Comment: You can add a copy constructor to the Parent class that accepts a Parent parameter and copies all its properties. Then you can call the constructor using `myParent = new Parent(myChild);`

Comment: Assuming that you're a native English speaker, you should have heard the expression "to cast something in a different light". That expression means to look at the same thing a different way. That's what it means to cast something in programming: you look at the same object via a reference of a different type. Not only does casting not change the type of the object, it doesn't change the object at all, i.e. it's still the very same object. If it's the same object, how could its type possibly change?

Comment: You can pretty much always relate OOP scenarios back to real-world object examples. Let's say that you have a pet cat and you need to take it to the vet. Your pet is type Cat. You put it into a carrier and take it to the vet. They don't know what you have in your carrier other than it's an animal. They know you have a pet Animal. When you open the carrier and take out your pet, they see that it is a Cat. They now know your per is a Cat. You had a Cat reference, you cast it as type Animal and then cast that as type Cat. Did the actual cat change at any time?

Comment: I think this may be a misunderstanding of how the c# type system works.

Comment: @Wyck - Yes class Child : Parent. And you are also correct that its using MemberwiseeClone.  Ah, I thought it changed the underlying objects type.  Looks like I need to do something else then.

Comment: @MichaelLiu - thanks. I was hoping that I dont need to do that due to the number of parameters the class has, but looks like an option thanks.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - thanks, thats some good explanations.  Always a learning day. :-)

Comment: @Fildor - you're right.